# How to make eshell-autojump case insensitive under Linux

Tags: emacs, eshell

Under Linux, **eshell-autojump** will do case sensitive matching which I just find a nuisance. I've tried to circumvent this by advising **eshell/j** with a **eshell-under-windows-p** that always returns t but to my chagrin **eshell-under-windows-p** invoked in **eshell/j** is unaffected by **cl-letf**. I've modified my **eshell/j** a bit to give me some debug info:

```
;; Modified eshell/j inside eshell-autojump.el to this

(defun eshell/j (&rest args)           ; all but first ignored
  "Jump to a directory you often cd to.
This compares the argument with the list of directories you usually jump to.
Without an argument, list the ten most common directories.
With a positive integer argument, list the n most common directories.
Otherwise, call `eshell/cd' with the result."
  (setq args (eshell-flatten-list args))
  (let ((path (car args))
        (candidates (eshell-autojump-candidates))
        (case-fold-search (eshell-under-windows-p))
        result)
    (when (not path)
      (setq path 10))
    (message "case-fold-search = %S" case-fold-search)
    (message "eshell-under-windows-p returns %s from inside eshell/j" (eshell-under-windows-p))
    (if (and (integerp path) (> path 0))
        (progn
          (let ((n (nthcdr (1- path) candidates)))
            (when n
              (setcdr n nil)))
          (eshell-lisp-command (mapconcat 'identity candidates "\n")))
      (while (and candidates (not result))
        (if (string-match path (car candidates))
            (setq result (car candidates))
          (setq candidates (cdr candidates))))
      (eshell/cd result))))
```

My **init.el** adds the advice to attempt to make **eshell/j** caseless by trying to trick it to think we are on Windows:

```
;; Added to init.el
  (require 'eshell-autojump)
  (advice-add 'eshell/j :around
    (lambda (orig-fun &rest xs)
      (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'eshell-under-windows-p) (lambda () t)))
        (progn (message "eshell-under-windows-p returns %s from lambda" (eshell-under-windows-p)) (apply orig-fun xs)))))
```

But all I get in **Messages** buffer when I try to jump in eshell is:

```
;; I get in *Messages*
eshell-under-windows-p returns t from lambda
case-fold-search = nil
eshell-under-windows-p returns nil from inside eshell/j
```

My rookie knowledge of elisp is not enough to wrestle with probable scoping issues here. Can anyone decode why **eshell-under-window-p** is unaffected when called from **eshell/j** here?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. **cl-letf** does not work for byte compiled functions. As eshell-autojump is a package it gets byte compiled upon installation and **cl-letf** cannot be used to modify it's internal behavior.

Finally I've managed to trick **eshell/j** to be case insensitive by:

```
  (defun my/eshell-j-case-insensitive (orig-fun &rest args)
    "Advice function to make `eshell/j' case-insensitive."
    (let ((original-system-type system-type))
      (unwind-protect
        (progn
          (setq system-type 'windows-nt) ; Temporarily set system-type to Windows
          (apply orig-fun args))
        (setq system-type original-system-type)))) ; Restore the original system-type
  (advice-add 'eshell/j :around #'my/eshell-j-case-insensitive)
```